# How to hide these icons on the menu bar after Ubuntu installation

Tags: icons, menu, menu-bar

After installation of Ubuntu 22.10 I decided to hide all those icons on my side menu bar, but there is no way to do this. When I press right-click there are usually two options: "New window" and "Unmount" or one simple "mount" when I press "unmount". When I tried "unmounting" - nothing really happened.
How can I remove it from my eyes?
What I did earlier: I have installed Ubuntu 22.10, then logged in Gnome -> Google account... And that's it..!
I have dual booted Windows 10 and Ubuntu.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/gyP9K.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/OLouv.jpg

Answer (score 0):

This is simple to fix

Go to `Settings > Appearance` and navigate down the screen to `Configure dock behaviour` and in the pop up click on `Show Volume and Devices` to remove them.